# Lua find operand in a string

Tags: lua

I have a Lua string like "382+323" or "32x291" or "94-23", how can I check and return the position of the operands?

I found `String.find(s, "[+x-]")` did not work. Any ideas?

```
th> str = '5+3'
th> string.find(str, '[+-x]')
1   1
th> string.find(str, '[+x-]')
2   2
```

Comment: [It works](http://ideone.com/ZPKl34). Show your exact code, including the test case.

Comment: "[+x-]" seems work, but "[+-x]" will return different result. Why?

Comment: "-" is a special character inside a `[]` set. If you write `[+-x]` it will be interpreted as a character range, like `[a-z]` but if the `-` appears as the last character then it is treated as just a `-`.

Comment: @C.Wang Just beginning Lua. In the basic lua interpreter, I have to type `print$(` every time I want to see the result of an operation. When I used python/ipthon, I just type the name of the variable to view its value. What Lua interpreter are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

[+-x] is a pattern match for 1 character in the range between "+" and "x".
When you want to use dash as character and not as the meta character you should start or end the character group with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Type an arithmetic expression, such as 382 x 3 / 15")
expr = io.read()
i = -1
while i do
    -- Find the next operator, starting from the position of the previous one. 
    -- The signals + and - are special characters, 
    -- so you have to use the % char to escape each one.
    -- [The find function returns the indices of s where this occurrence starts and ends][1].
    -- Here we are obtaining just the start index.
    i = expr:find("[%+x%-/]", i+1) 
    if i then
        print("Operator", expr:sub(i, i), "at position", i)
    end
end
```